# How to produce one condensed error message with ko.validation.group?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have many error groups which are executed as per condition to condition.

```
@errors1 = ko.validation.group [  @foo, @bar ]
@errors2 = ko.validation.group [ @x , @y, @z ]
@errors3 = ko.validation.group [ @apha , @beta, @gama ]
```

Now for some reason,I want to create a custom `<div>` error box which will display all its error messages one by one , something like

```
1. Foo is blank.
2. Bar is not equal to foo.
```

How can i ? I think if i am able to iterate observable which are inside that group programtically i might able to produce the above `div` eaisly ?

PS: i know i can use show error messages with `.showAllMessages()`.

Comment: So do want for every group messages to be displayed in the one div or one div per group?

Answer (score 2):

First you must turn off insertMessages so that messages aren't displayed next to the fields:

```
ko.validation.configure({
    insertMessages: false
});
```

Then set each validation group to an observable:

```
self.errors1 = ko.validation.group([self.firstName, self.lastName]);
```

Then in your view you can loop through the errors for each validation group at the top like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: errors1">
    <div data-bind="text: $data"></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pqd5ds1x/1/